# RGB image filter in java

Tags: java, image, filter

I want to look my pictures like that:

[image]

I want to filter the image by pressing a button.
Currently, I have a `BufferedImage` and I don't know how to set the pixels.

This converts my picture into the blue one but I don't know why and how can I set green and red?

```
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();

        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
          for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p & 0xff;

            img.setRGB(x,y,r);
          }
        }
        this.lblFilteredImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but it looks like you're separating the RGB pixels.  In the red image, you would have to set the green and blue part of the color to zero.  In the green image, you would have to set the red and blue part of the color to zero.  In the blue image, you would have to set the red and the green part of the color to zero.

Comment: Look, I've updated my question. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the separate color images is to zero out the other colors.

[image: RGB Display]

This GUI model class generates the red, green, and blue images from an original image by changing the mask bits.

```
package com.ggl.rgbdisplay.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class RGBDisplayModel {

    private BufferedImage originalImage;
    private BufferedImage redImage;
    private BufferedImage greenImage;
    private BufferedImage blueImage;

    public BufferedImage getOriginalImage() {
        return originalImage;
    }

    public void setOriginalImage(BufferedImage originalImage) {
        this.originalImage = originalImage;
        this.redImage = createColorImage(originalImage, 0xFFFF0000);
        this.greenImage = createColorImage(originalImage, 0xFF00FF00);
        this.blueImage = createColorImage(originalImage, 0xFF0000FF);
    }

    public BufferedImage getRedImage() {
        return redImage;
    }

    public BufferedImage getGreenImage() {
        return greenImage;
    }

    public BufferedImage getBlueImage() {
        return blueImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createTestImage() {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();

        for (int y = 0; y < bufferedImage.getHeight(); y += 20) {
            if (y % 40 == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            g.fillRect(0, y, bufferedImage.getWidth(), 20);
        }

        g.dispose();
        return bufferedImage;
    }

    private BufferedImage createColorImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int mask) {
        BufferedImage colorImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),
                originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getType());

        for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < originalImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                int pixel = originalImage.getRGB(x, y) & mask;
                colorImage.setRGB(x, y, pixel);
            }
        }

        return colorImage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily separate the red, green and blue values through the `java.awt.Color` class, which takes the color value from `img.getRGB(x,y)` as a constructor Argument:

```
Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x,y));

int red = color.getRed();
int green = color.getGreen();
int blue = color.getBlue();
```

Now you can convert them back into the values needed for `img.setRGB()` through another `java.awt.Color` Object, which can also take red, green, and blue values in the constructor `Color(red, green, blue)` and has the method `.getRGB()` to get the full color code back:

```
int onlyRed = new Color(red, 0, 0).getRGB();
int onlyGreen = new Color(0, green, 0).getRGB();
int onlyBlue = new Color(0, 0, blue).getRGB();
```

Now to get a completely red image you just have to write `img.setRGB(x, y, onlyRed);`.